# How can I edit columns of numbers in vim using conditionals?

Tags: linux, command-line, vim

If I have, for example, a column of numbers:

```
4
6
8
10
12
```

Is there a way in Vim that I could find all numbers higher than 8, than do math only with these numbers? Obtaining a new column as a result:

```
4
6
8
(10+2)=12
(12+2)=14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this kind of substitution using the `\=` special replace expression. Check out [`:help sub-replace-special`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-special) for all the details, but here's how this specific replacement could work:

```
%s/\d\+/\=str2nr(submatch(0)) > 8 ? str2nr(submatch(0)) + 2 : submatch(0)
```

In the replacement part of the `:substitute` command, after the `\=`, `submatch(0)` gives you the full match. The `str2nr` global function converts that to a number.

If you'd like the logic to be more readable, you could extract it to a function:

```
function! IncrementNumber(number_string)
  let number = str2nr(a:number_string)
  if number > 8
    let number += 2
  endif

  return number
endfunction
```

You can put that in your `.vimrc`, and tweak it, set the threshold of `8` as a parameter, etc, and then call this on the file:

```
%s/\d\+/\=IncrementNumber(submatch(0))
```